# cygwin file not found on network windows drive, possible issue with spaces

Tags: windows, cygwin, absolute-path

to try and not over complicate my issue i'm using cygwin and have two windows computers on a network sharing data.  i'm trying to add a logo to some photos and are having a tough time with finding the logo file with cygwin in this code

`for f in *.jpg; do
convert "$f" \
-gravity southeast \
-draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "//deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/logo2.png"' \
-write //deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/og-rotate-logo/"$f" \
-resize 1200x1200 \
//deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/1200px/"$f"
done`

I have no problem when using cd to get to this location with cygwin

`//deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/`

but then when using the above loop to watermark the files cygwin can't find the logo file and I assume it won't write to the correct directories after either because of the same problem.  I actually got it working using

`../logo2.png`

but really want to use the actual address like I'm trying.  Any help with this is very much appreciated!

Comment: try  "//deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/og-rotate-logo/$f"   "//deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/1200px/$f"

Comment: @matzeri YES!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This is what finally worked! 'code' for f in *.jpg; do
convert "$f" \
-verbose \
-gravity southeast \
-draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "//deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/logo2.png"' \
-write "//deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/og-rotate-logo/$f" \
-resize 1200x1200 \
"//deepfrogphotopc/L Xotio Passport/temp/1200px/$f"
done